# GWT RPC fails with no error and no exception

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

I have an RPC service that that logs in a user. If the username and password is valid, everything works great. However, if the username and password is not valid, the server side code seems to execute fine, but the `onFailure()` method of the callback is fired. There are no errors or exceptions other than the `onFailure()` method itself. The exception that appears client side is the generic "500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details"

I've wrapped all the code in a try/catch block to ensure no exceptions are being thrown at runtime.

Here's the method in question:

```
public OmsConsumer login(String username, String password, String ip) {

    OmsUser user = auth.validate(username, password, ip);

    OmsConsumer consumer;

    if(user.isValid()){
        logger.info("User is Valid");

        consumer = getConsumerByPersonId(user.getPersonId());       
    }else {
        logger.info("User is INVALID");

        consumer = new OmsConsumer();

        consumer.setValid(false);
        consumer.setErrors(user.getErrors());

            logger.info("Errors: " + consumer.getErrors().size());
    }
    return consumer;
}
```

Again, when `user.isValid()` returns true, there is no problem. The `onFailure()` is only fired when `user.isValid()` returns false.

I'm stumped on this one, so any debug tips or advice are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you go through the server-side method in debug mode?

Comment: Have you looked into the server-log?

Comment: If the code you have shown is server side then where is the try/catch block?

Comment: I've never been able to get debug mode to function correctly.

Comment: Yes, the Server log shows now errors.

Comment: I removed the try/catch blocks, and several logger.info calls, for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips. I ended up finding the problem in a different class. The OmsError class implemented Serializable, but did not have a no-parameter constructor. When debugging I wrapped the entire method in a try/catch, so I'm not sure why I wasn't getting an exception from that. However, once I added `public OmsError(){}`  to the OmsError class, everything works great.

Comment: For clarity, `OmsUser.getErrors` returns a list of OmsErrors.

Comment: OmsError was not thrown, but it is used in Serialized classes so serialization fails after it returns from procedure you are calling